# How to use Deepstream SDK to take a video and just extract the frames in jpg

Tags: gstreamer, pipeline, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-deepstream

I want to know if someone can help with a Deepstream model code that takes a video in the source and outputs frames of that particular video in jpg.

It would be helpful if you can share the Gstreamer CPP or Python code as well.

Comment: have you tried this: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/frame-extraction-using-deepstream-python-app/109748/2

Answer (score 0):

You can use Deepstream's official [Python segmentation example](https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/deepstream_python_apps/blob/master/apps/deepstream-segmentation/deepstream_segmentation.py) and modify it for your case of reading and saving JPEG frames.

The following pipeline should work: `source -> jpegparser -> decoder -> streammux -> fakesink`. You can attach your probe saving function directly to `fakesink` instead of `seg` component of the original pipeline. Also, for how to create the `fakesink` component you can check another Python example on [this line](https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/deepstream_python_apps/blob/master/apps/deepstream-test4/deepstream_test_4.py#L395)

Comment: Can you share some code, please? I am new to this tech stack!
Thanks.

Comment: Can you check this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69305322/using-gstreamer-to-extract-frames-on-videos-simultaneously